# Python-Jenkins API Connection Error

Tags: python, jenkins

I'm trying to use python-jenkins to connect to a jenkins instance.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
import jenkins

JENKINS_URL = 'xxxx'
JENKINS_USER = 'yyyy'
JENKINS_PASSWORD = 'zzzz'

server = jenkins.Jenkins(JENKINS_URL, username=JENKINS_USER, password=JENKINS_PASSWORD)

jobs = server.get_jobs()

for job in jobs:
    print "Job: {0}".format(job.name)
```

The username and password are valid; I can log in to jenkins via the web using them without issue. However, here, I get an error. The traceback I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "apitest.py", line 11, in <module>
        jobs = server.get_jobs()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 540, in get_jobs
        return self.get_info()['jobs']
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 422, in get_info
        Request(self.server + INFO)))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 312, in jenkins_open
        self.maybe_add_crumb(req)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 230, in maybe_add_crumb
        self.server + CRUMB_URL), add_crumb=False)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 330, in jenkins_open
        e.code, e.msg)
jenkins.JenkinsException: Error in request. Possibly authentication failed [500]: Server Error
```

Can anyone shed any light on the problem? I'm using python-jenkins version 0.4.8, and our jenkins box is version 1.541. The only other useful data point I can think of is that the jenkins box is configured to support https access only.

N.B. I've also tried jenkinsapi, but get a similar error

Comment: is there anything in your jenkins logs at the relevant time?

Comment: No, nothing at all. I could increase the log level, but I'm guessing any such messages would be error level anyway...

Comment: I am also facing this problem. I don't think it is because of using token. For me it looks like the problem is with Auth backend. I am using AD backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that I was using the password for the account, whereas actually you need to use the API token.

The documentation (and variable names) in jenkinsapi don't make this clear at all!