# Need a way to pass Jenkins API token to python-jenkins wrapper

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins

I'm using Python 3 (version 3.5.2) and the following [Python-Jenkins Wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/python-jenkins/) to control the Jenkins Server (with version 2.298) via the API. The end goal is to control the jenkins jobs, build nodes using the python-jenkins wrapper. I'm looking for avenues to pass API credentials instead of using regular user password.

I have researched the documentation and the comments specified under [Example 1](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#example-1-get-version-of-jenkins)

The following snippet works with *password* without any issues,

```
server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://localhost:8080', username='myuser', password='mypassword')
user = server.get_whoami()
version = server.get_version()
print('Hello %s from Jenkins %s' % (user['fullName'], version))
```

but for security reasons I intend to use the *API token* instead of *password*, I slightly tweaked the example snippet as mentioned below, this piece of python code does not work.

```
server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://localhost:8080', username='myuser', password='myapitoken')
user = server.get_whoami()
version = server.get_version()
print('Hello %s from Jenkins %s' % (user['fullName'], version))
```

The Error viewed in the console with the above code-snippet is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 140, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I have referred the following resource on Jenkins official [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/authenticating-scripted-clients/), this does not provide a pythonic way of providing the API credentials. Also I have searched for some more inputs/answers [HERE on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268025/python-jenkins-api-connection-error) but unfortunately did not find relevant input or answers.

Requesting for some inputs to resolve the above error, I would like to use *API token in place of password.*

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find the problem?

Comment: Sadly, no, using a different way since then.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Jenkins control panel create the API Token in Dashboard -> People -> Select your account

Go to the configurations and API Token part. Generate API Token and just simply use it in the place of password as seen in that example code. Don't lose the toke, because that is the only time you get to see it. Copy it some where safe.